# Google Cloud module not visible in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-platform

I'm running the latest version of `Android Studio`.

In order to use Google App Engine, I've tried to follow [these simple steps](https://cloud.google.com/mobile/app_engine/add_module).

My problem is that no module type relative to `Google Cloud` is visible, as you can see :

[image]

Can you help me ? I have no idea and nothing on the web helped me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Faced the same issue today. Turned out that i have disabled Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio plugin to reduce memory. Open Settings under File Menu, then enabling the plugin and re-starting Android Studio resolved the issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was the problem. As I forgot to answer my own question, I will accept your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think one of the reasons could be because you have not installed Google Repository or similar in SDK Manager. Can you check it?